# Change CDI sessionscoped bean in a Runnable submitted to ManagedExecutorService from a different thread throws a ContextNotActiveException

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have the following method called in a REST service which needs to return immediatly:

```
@Inject
private ScheduleManager scheduleManager;

@Resource(name = "DefaultManagedExecutorService")
ManagedExecutorService executor;

public String solveSchedule(@PathParam("conferenceId") Long conferenceId) {
    executor.submit(new SolverCallable());
    return "Solved started.";
}
```

It submits this inner class to be executed on another thread

```
private class SolverCallable implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Schedule bestSchedule = ...; // do some long computation
        scheduleManager.setSchedule(bestSchedule); // throws ContextNotActiveException
    }

}
```

**How can I change the session scoped bean in the Runnable with the result of a long computation?**

Comment: I'd say you need to pass the instance to the Runnable. Since `SovlerCallable` will be executed on another thread there's no active CDI session context associated with that thread.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  Even if you pass a reference, the reference will be lost since all you get is a proxy.  The proxy is meant to look at active threads and do work on those threads.  When it's getting to your managed executor, the thread isn't part of the original HTTP session and as a result, you get the `ContextNotActiveException`.

Technically speaking, HTTP sessions aren't well understood for JAX-RS, there's no actual requirement in the spec that a JAX-RS resource participates in an HTTP session.

The most common workaround I recommend to people is to have some centralized location to store these types of big results and have the session scoped object read from there.  Have the executor talk to that component as well.  That could be as simple as a hashmap keyed off of HTTP session id.

To get the session id, just call `HttpSession.getId()`.  You can also destroy the map reference by using a `@PreDestroy` method in one of your `@SessionScoped` beans to call the central spot and destroy the reference.

As far as the thread goes, I can't think of any way to kill it other than to be able to inject a reference to the runnable from your session scoped bean (or make the runnable your session scoped bean) and tell it to cease the thread from there.

```
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Runnable,Serializable {

    private HttpSession httpSession;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        httpSession = CDI.current().select(HttpSession.class).get();
        // register the session
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void unregister() {
        // unregister the session
        // kill the thread.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use a centralized location, because when the session times, the memory should be freed (and and such tasks still running should be discarded).

Comment: Is there any way for me to get the session map from the task thread (presuming I can pass the session ID to the task) and then retrieve the ScheduleManager from that session map?

Comment: I added some more content to my answer to help.